# change div value without ID or class

Tags: html, css

How do I change the value of DIV if it has no ID or class? here's a sample code:

```
<div id=1>
   <div id=2>
     <div id=3>
       <div>
        <div id=4>
            <div><span>CHANGE HERE</span></div>
        </div> 
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to access the inside div use `#4 div`

Comment: or if you just have 1 div with no id or class than you may try the :not selector

Comment: you want to use jquery or css?

Comment: Hi all, I edited my code, its something like that,and I would like to use javascript or css if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the style of your div you could do the following:

```
#4>div{
}
```

this means you will apply the class on the child  divs of div with id=4.
But you cannot change its value with the use off css. Use js instead.
Also, please change the id's of your divs so it won't be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Can be accessed by following the DOM tree

For your code

div's can be access like

body div{ }- select the first div tag
body div div{ }- select the second div tag
likewise it goes by the tree structure 
For accessing the last div and span-> body div div div div div span{ } can be used
By this way you can select and use the tag without specifying the id or class

Check the css pseudo code for more